# Update a variable on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this variable called counter that starts at zero. And I want to update it everytime the user clicks on a certain button

```
window.counter = 0;


jQuery("#someButton").click(function(){


    window.counter += 1;


})
```

So everytime the user clicks the button counter increase by 1.

Comment: Well, what's your question?

Comment: `var counter = 0;` then `$('#yourButton').click(function(){ counter++;})`

Comment: Why do you use global `window` here ?

Answer (score 0):

it already works... variable increases

https://jsfiddle.net/pouj1g92/

i added jsfiddle to test your self...

```
window.counter = 0;

$("#someButton").click(function(){
    window.counter += 1;
    alert(window.counter);
});
```

Comment: Yes, apparently there was something wrong with that specific page I was testing it on. I tried jsfiddle and it was fine and then I tried another page and it also worked

Comment: post a link if you want.